# What is the English equivalent to the Russian proverb glossed “Who has never tasted bitter, knows not what is sweet.”?

Tags: meaning, idioms, proverbs

I wanted to share a Russian proverb in reply to a tweet that cited:

- “Defeat is not the worst of failures. Not to have tried is the true failure.” George E. Woodberry

The Russian proverb “За битого - двух небитых дают” [is translated in wiki](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0_%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82) as
“Who has never tasted bitter, knows not what is sweet.”

I find this equivalent fails to convey the original spirit and meaning. The literal phrase is something like: "One defeated (beaten) is exchanged for (equals to) two undefeated (never beaten)"

What would be a more literal and more exact translation of this proverb in English?

Comment: Montrose's toast is tolerably close to the sentiment: "He either fears his fate too much,
Or his desserts are small, Who dares not put it to the touch, To win or lose it all.”

Comment: Perhaps "A thorn of experience is worth a wilderness of advice?"

Answer (score 7):

Maybe *“We learn little from victory, much from defeat.”*

Or, in-between the two meanings you provided, a quote from M. S. Forbes: *“Victory is sweetest when you've known defeat.”*

Answer (score 1):

I don't speak Russian, so this answer is working with just the English explanations in your question.

The sense of the Woodberry quote that sparked this train of thought is that *trying* is worth risking failure for. This is echoed in your own translation of the Russian proverb - that one defeated person is worth two who have never been defeated, presumably because they didn't even try.

An English idiom that echoes this sentiment is [Tennyson's quote](https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/alfred_lord_tennyson_153702):

> 'Tis better to have loved and lost than never to have loved at all.

The quote lacks the war context, but since you're after a literary allusion, I trust you wouldn't mind stretching the literary link between [love and war](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/all%27s%20fair%20in%20love%20and%20war). Tennyson's quote carries the idea you're after - that even if you fail, the experience itself is worth the attempt.